# How to solve problem with Invalid RSA condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa, mega-api

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/megabot/megabot.py", line 5, in module
    m = mega.login(email, password)
  File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/megabot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mega/mega.py", line 45, in login
    self._login_user(email, password)
  File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/megabot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mega/mega.py", line 77, in _login_user
    self._login_process(resp, password_aes)
  File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/megabot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mega/mega.py", line 131, in _login_process
    rsa_decrypter = RSA.construct(
  File "/Users/mac/PycharmProjects/megabot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 604, in construct
    raise ValueError("Invalid RSA condition")
ValueError: Invalid RSA condition
```

Using module mega.py (https://pypi.org/project/mega.py/)

```py
from mega import Mega
mega = Mega()
password = 'here is my password'
email = 'here is my email'
m = mega.login(email, password)
```

I tried to login using a temporary anonymous account, and exit code was 0.